# How to get composer to copy a local package instead of making a symlink?

Tags: drupal, composer-php

I am very new to composer and trying to get it to install a package from a local directory in the project. Using a type of "path" is working except it is making a symlink to the source directory. I want it to make a copy instead.

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "assets/modules/mymodule",
            "options": {
                "symlink": false
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "drupal/mymodule",
                "version": "1.0",
                "type": "drupal-module",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "assets/modules/mymodule",
                    "type": "path"
                }
            }
        },

[...]
```

I'm defining the package so that the Drupal composer setup will put it into the same location as other contributed modules. That part is fine.

I tried adding "options": { "symlink": false } to the repository definition but that does nothing. I've read that using "vcs" would make a copy, but nowhere that I can use that type legally makes a difference. The package source is just a directory of files, not a repository, is that the problem?

Comment: hmn, just red the docs and `symlink: false` should do the trick, after adding that did you remove any already created symlinks?

Comment: ... and run composer update/install again?

Comment: Yeah, none of that made any difference. The people involved decided they preferred a symlink anyway, in the end, so I stopped trying to figure it out.